# Resize textarea and add scrollbar after third line. Angular 1.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I work with AngularJS 1.5 and I have `<form>` and inside of it `<textarea>` 1 row size. And I need it to be resized up to 3 lines when user inputs something. And after that scroll must appear. For now I have following solution:

```
.directive('testAutoResize', testAutoResize);

  function testAutoResize() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      replace: false,
      scope: {},
      link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
        elem.on('keyup', function() {
          elem[0].style.height = elem[0].value ? elem[0].scrollHeight + 'px' : 32 + 'px';
        });
      }
    };
}
```

Also I have CSS property `max-height: 72px;` to limit height of texarea.
So, I'm not really like it and how it works.
Can you advise something?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you like how it works? Will be fine to know what's the expected behaviour.

Comment: Scrollbar appears and disappears when new line added. And stays after third line. I need it to only appear once. After textarea is resized to three lines.

Comment: What happens if you change `keyup` with `keydown`?

Comment: Nothing new. Just the same